# Dynamic JPanels error

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I hava CardLayout and want to have changing panels on it. For that I wrote my JFrame Class:

```
public class GUI_NewList extends javax.swing.JFrame {

CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();

public GUI_NewList() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLayout(layout);

    JPanel paChoose = new Choose();

    layout.addLayoutComponent(paChoose, "1");
    layout.show(paChoose, "1");
}
```

The class Choose:

```
public class Choose extends JPanel {

    public Choose() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        JButton btnPractice = new JButton("Practice");
        add(btnPractice);

        JButton btnNewList = new JButton("Create a new List");
        add(btnNewList);

        JButton btnEditList = new JButton("Edit a List");
        add(btnEditList);
    }
}
```

If I run this I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
```

Could you please tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an MCVE that fixes the problem. See code comments for details of the problem(s).

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI_NewList extends JFrame {

    CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();

    public GUI_NewList() {
        this.setLayout(layout);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel paChoose = new Choose();

        // this only adds it to the layout, not the container.
        layout.addLayoutComponent(paChoose, "1");
        // this adds it to the container (the content pane)
        add(paChoose);
        // the container of interest is the content pane.
        layout.show(this.getContentPane(), "1");

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            new GUI_NewList();
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class Choose extends JPanel {

    public Choose() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        JButton btnPractice = new JButton("Practice");
        add(btnPractice);

        JButton btnNewList = new JButton("Create a new List");
        add(btnNewList);

        JButton btnEditList = new JButton("Edit a List");
        add(btnEditList);
    }
}
```

**Note:** There is no good case here for extending either `JFrame` ***or*** `JPanel`.